# Generating random data

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to generate random data for 'ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY' in a 3-mer form (like, AEF) using following script, but in the outputs I have gotten many similar 3-mers. Would you please advise me on how to do, not to get similar results or remove the same 3-mer?

Thanks in advance,
Berk

```
import random

def random_AA_seq(length):
    return ''.join(random.choice('ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY') for i in range(length))

list_size = 10000
lengths = []

for j in range(list_size):
    a = int(random.normalvariate(3, 0))
    print random_AA_seq(a)
```

Comment: Similar as in `ABC + ABC` or similar as in `AAA`?

Comment: Similar as in ABC + ABC. I need AAA, but not the (AAA + AAA)

Answer (score 1):

To remove the same items, just make it a set:

```
print set(random_AA_seq(a))
```

To get **all** possible permutations, you could also use itertools...

```
from itertools import permutations

length = 3
print permutations('ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY', length)
```

... and pick your 3-mers randomly afterwards.

Comment: And `list(itertools.combincations(..., 3))` if OP doesn't like "AAA" trimers

Comment: @qarma: `itertools.permutations` already excludes multiple values in the same result set :)

Answer (score 1):

Per comments:

```
alphabet = "ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY"
all_trimers = map("".join, itertools.product(* [alphabet] * 3))
a_few_distinct_trimers = random.sample(all_trimers, 42)
```

Comment: I need AAA but not AAA + AAA

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(3))
```

should be fine

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**, the following script will return a list of 3mers of the length required. Each 3mer will occur in the list once:

```
import random

def random_3mers(length):
    seqs = set()

    while len(seqs) < length:
        seqs.add("".join(random.sample("ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY", 3)))

    lseqs = list(seqs)
    random.shuffle(lseqs)
    return lseqs

for three_mer in random_3mers(10):
    print three_mer
```

For a length of 10, the following type of output will be displayed:

```
MKY
KWV
PRY
WKQ
YGI
ANQ
GFL
RQE
SCN
GRY
```

Comment: Yes, but I need the 3-mer items (like AAA, ABC and ...)

Comment: No problem, then just pass 3 as your length.

Comment: Again, I'm facing with a lot of duplicated 3-mers like ACF, ACF, ACF MNP, MNP and ....

Comment: Ok, I have redone the script, hopefully this will be nearer to what you need.

Comment: How can I get the 3-mer items only in one column and without comma?

Comment: Display them one at a time from the list.